# How can I identify phase transition from a plot of Ising model?

Tags: ising-model, phase-transitions

The following is the plot of my Ising Model simulation:

[image]

The upper one is for $T=3.3$, and the lower one is for $T=1.5$. Otherwise, in both cases, boltzmann=$1$, MC steps=$1000000$, and the lattice dimension are $40\times40$.

How can I identify phase transition in this plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a having a phase transitions, small changes in parameters like temperature or pressure causes a large-scale, qualitative change in the state of a system.

To characterize the state of the system, you can use several thermodynamic variables like internal energy, magnetization, specific heat, etc.

The figure below show a phase transition:

[image: sssss]
Caption: *Ising phase transition as seen from classical Monte Carlo simulations with t′=0.15t and U=10t. Panels (a), (b), and (c) show the temperature dependence of the magnetization, susceptibility, and Binder cumulant, respectively. The insets are zoomed-in plots of the same data over a narrower temperature range. The temperature is plotted in units of J=4t2/U, with kB taken to be unity. Panels (d), (e), and (f) show the same data after scaling using the critical exponents of the 2D Ising model.*

Reference: M. Karmakar and R. Ganesh. "*Attractive Hubbard model as an SO(3) system of competing phases: Supersolid order and its thermal melting*". Phys. Rev. Research **2**, 023304, 2020. DOI: [10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.023304](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.023304).

Your plot is Energy vs Steps, but to detect phase transition, you need to plot Energy vs Temperature, for example. You can get an average energy for the last N steps for several temperatures and make a plot, then look for large variations in Energy.

Comment: What is $U$ here? The total energy?

Comment: What do u mean by $4t2/U$?

Comment: Please, read the publication. It is Open Access. The used Hamiltonian is shown in Eq. (1).